# Windows Batch File Quote Problems

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file

I've got the following code, but when it is executed there are problems with the quotes: the substring methods need to use :=", but I don't know how to combine them with for example :~0,9.

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

set var=%1

if %var:~0,9%=="phpfile:/" (
    set url = %var:~9% 
) else (
    set url = %var:~10%
)

if "%var:~-1%"=="\" (
    set url = %url:~0,-1%"
)
if "%var:~-1%"=="/" (
    set url = %url:~0,-1%"
)

START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuSphere\PhpED\7.0\phped.exe" %url:"=%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax bugs in your code.

Don't add spaces in `SET` statements, else you got variable names with spaces `url<space>` instead of `url`.

The `if %var:~0,9%=="phpfile:/" (` must be quoted, else the parser will not work as expected.

The trailing quote at `set url = %url:~0,-1%"` will add a quote at the end, I suppose you need something like `set "url=%url:~0,-1%"`

```
set "var=%~1"

if "%var:~0,9%"=="phpfile:/" (
    set "url=%var:~9%"
) else (
    set "url=%var:~10%"
)

if "%var:~-1%"=="\" (
    set "url=%url:~0,-1%"
)
if "%var:~-1%"=="/" (
    set "url=%url:~0,-1%"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but there is still a problem:
the first rule gives if ""phpfile:/"=="phpfile:/" (

Comment: No, only if you call the batch file `myParser.bat "phpfile:/xyz/"`. Then you should change `set var=%1` to `set "var=%~1"`